# div gap at top of page?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a clearfix in my style.css and everything worked fine on other projects. All of a sudden there is a gap appearing in my browser, causing the div container move approx. 20px down, and I don't know what I do wrong here?

My code runs good in JS Fiddle I think. Therefore I put a picture in it where you can see the not wanted 20px "top - margin". What might be causing this?

### Edit

I've found the issue. it was the h1 tag. If you replace h1 in both, html and css, with the p tag, it works perfectly fine after setting the p margin to 0. But why is this?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="de">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/normalize.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lobster|Raleway:300,400,500,700" rel="stylesheet">
    <!--CSS-Font : font-family: 'Lobster', cursive;
    font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif; -->
     <title>Appearence</title>
</head>
<div class="container">
  <body>
    <div class="main-header background-color clearfix">
      <header id="main-header-top" class=" ">
        <div class="logo-title ">
          <a href="index.html"><h1>Operation<span>Mars</span>.com</h1></a>
        </div>
      </header>
    </div>
  </body>
  <!--body-end-->
  <footer>
  </footer>
</div>
</html>


* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: 'Dosis', sans-serif;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

html,
body{
  position:relative;
}

.main-header{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
}
.background-color{
  background-color: black;
}

.logo-title {
  width: 400px;
  height: auto;
  left: 50%;
  position: relative;
  margin-left: -200px;
}
.logo-title a{
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.logo-title a h1{
  font-size: 60px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
  font-family: 'Lobster', cursive;
}

.logo-title a h1 span{
  color:#ff7256;
  font-family: 'Lobster', cursive;
  font-size: 70px;
}
/*clearfix*/
.clearfix:before,
.clearfix:after { /*Inhalt hinzufügen*/
  content: "";
  display: table;
}

.clearfix:after {
  clear:both;
}
```

[image: gap appearing]

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/H76bq/248/

Comment: You can't have HTML before or after your body tags. check your code for validity first.

Answer (score 0):

try this.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: 'Dosis', sans-serif;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

html,
body{
  position:relative;
}

.main-header{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
}
.background-color{
  background-color: black;
}

.logo-title {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  
}
.logo-title a{
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  left: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  transform:translateX(-50%);
}
.logo-title a h1{
  font-size: 60px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
  font-family: 'Lobster', cursive;
}

.logo-title a h1 span{
  color:#ff7256;
  font-family: 'Lobster', cursive;
  font-size: 70px;
}
/*clearfix*/
.clearfix:before,
.clearfix:after { /*Inhalt hinzufügen*/
  content: "";
  display: table;
}

.clearfix:after {
  clear:both;
}
```

```html
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="de">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/normalize.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lobster|Raleway:300,400,500,700" rel="stylesheet">
    <!--CSS-Font : font-family: 'Lobster', cursive;
    font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif; -->
     <title>Appearence</title>
</head>
<div class="container">
  <body>
    <div class="main-header background-color clearfix">
      <header id="main-header-top" class=" ">
        <div class="logo-title ">
          <a href="index.html"><h1>Operation<span>Mars</span>.com</h1></a>
        </div>
      </header>
    </div>
  </body>
  <!--body-end-->
  <footer>
  </footer>
</div>
</html>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! To improve your answer--for the OP and future developers--it helps to explain why it solves the problem described in the question.

Comment: what's the difference? I tried it, there is still this random margin.